# Resetting index to flat after pivot_table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe `df`

```
           Datum    HH  DayPrecipitation
9377    2016-01-26  18  3
9378    2016-01-26  19  4
9379    2016-01-26  20  11
9380    2016-01-26  21  23
9381    2016-01-26  22  12
```

Which I converted to wide format using

```
df.pivot_table(index = 'Datum', columns='HH' ,values = 'DayPrecipitation')
```

This  leaves me with a double column

```
     HH     18  19  20  21  22
  Datum                 
2016-01-26  3   4   11  23  12
```

I want to make the column look like this and rename the columns:

```
   Datum  col1 col2  col3 col4 col5 col6            
2016-01-26  1    3    4    11   23   12
```

However when I use `reset_index` it just adds another index column and does not remove the multi_index. 
Does anyone know how to achieve said table? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `[]` in `['DayPrecipitation']` for avoid `MultiIndex in columns`, then set new columns names by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) and last convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
L = [f'col{x+1}' for x in range(df['HH'].nunique())]
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index = 'Datum', columns='HH' ,values = 'DayPrecipitation')
         .rename_axis(None,axis=1)
         .set_axis(L, inplace=False, axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
        Datum  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0  2016-01-26     3     4    11    23    12
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my question because it does not achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
```